# Heroku Spring Postgres (Maven) [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:

Tags: maven, spring-boot, heroku

Не могу задеплоить приложение на heroku, деплоить пытаюсь с помощью heroku cli.

создаю git init
дальше логинюсь в heroku : heroku login
git add .
git commit -m "comment"
git push heroku master
База данных на сайте heroku подключена
p.s При запуске приложения на localhost, все отлично взлетает.
Ошибка выдается после команды git push heroku master 
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project Pet: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]

Полный код ошибки:

```
remote:        [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
remote:        [INFO] Compiling 14 source files to /tmp/build_9d475cefb6aba75f42ef04bc988c4107/target/classes
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [INFO] Total time:  13.323 s
remote:        [INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-23T08:41:48Z
remote:        [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
remote:        [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project Pet: Fatal error compiling: invalid target release: 11 -> [Help 1]
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
remote:        [ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
remote:        [ERROR]
remote:        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
remote:        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
remote:
remote:  !     ERROR: Failed to build app with Maven
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! If you can't find the issue in application code,
remote:        please submit a ticket so we can help: https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Java app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to milliapp.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/milliapp.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/milliapp.git'
```

[Ссылка на приложение на гите](https://github.com/greeetings/Pet-s-life.git)

Answer (score 1):

Тоже столкнулся с такой проблемой. Решил её добавив файл system.properties  с таким кодом:

```
java.runtime.version=11
```

Answer (score -1):

такое же вылезало, удалось решить добавив в pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>
```

там подробнее описано, что к чему
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28291691/fatal-error-compiling-invalid-target-release-1-8-help-1